# Cucumber, Rspec: unicode symbols in output

Tags: unicode, character-encoding, internationalization, rspec, cucumber

I wonder if it is possible to make Cucumber output matching errors in Russian instead of this:

```
Сценарий: Успешное добавление кгиги     # features/books/add_book.feature:12
    Если я добавил книгу                  # features/step_definitions/books_steps.rb:3
    То я должен увидеть добавленную книгу # features/step_definitions/books_steps.rb:15
      expected there to be content "\320\235\320\260\320\267\320\262\320\260\320\275
\320\270\320\265 \320\272\320\275\320\270\320\263\320\270" in "\320\236\321\210\320\270\320
\261\320\272\320\260 502!\n...
```

Where "\320\235\320\260\320\267\320\262\320\260\320\275" is a Russian word. It may be a feature of Rspec. Any Ideas would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding

```
$KCODE='u'
```

to my **features/support/env.rb** helped a little:

```
А должен увидеть сообщение о том, что пароль неверен
      expected there to be content "Неверный прол\321\214"
```

This solution is only for 1.8.7 – in 1.9.3

```
# encoding: utf-8
```

works just fine